# Discharging capacitors on a computer motherboard for safety

Tags: capacitor, safety, discharge, motherboard

A daycare in my city has taken a donation of desktop and laptop computers for the older children to take apart.

I am concerned that the various capacitors would present a shock hazard for the children, and have volunteered to discharge them.

The original plan was to unplug the computer, hold the power button to discharge the PSU output capacitors, then cut off an ATX cable and short the rails to ground, which should take care of the electrolytic filter capacitors on the motherboard.

Would this create a floating potential that could cause a shock if someone were to be touching the case and something else that was properly grounded?

Also, would there be a good way to discharge the PSU input capacitors?

Comment: You're wasting your time. The voltages present anywhere on a PC motherboard (under normal circumstances) are nowhere near enough to present any kind of shock hazard - even while powered up and running.

Comment: The PSU is the only component with potentially hazardous voltages. Remove the PSU, and you're done. (Assuming you're not dealing with old CRT monitors as well.)

Comment: As for the PSU input caps, just let the PC sit on a desk for a few hours to be sure the caps discharge through the bleeder resistors.

Comment: Other hazards exceed voltage ( after taking @Dampmaskin advise), including RoHS non-compliance, leaky batteries, small-part choking hazard to name a few.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll probably just remove the PSUs then. I appreciate the advice, and will advise the daycare on the RoHS non-compliance and leaky batteries issues.

Comment: Laptop *batteries* are a bigger hazard than most people think.

Comment: There are potentially lots of **sharp edges** in a computer case, generally the cheaper the case, the more sharp edges. Older laptops might have cold cathode display backlights - broken glass and poisonous phosphors.

Comment: All electronics contain various noxious chemicals that you REALLY don't want in the hands of children. For example, Mercury, Lead, Cyanide and a whole bunch more that I can't spell. Also one has to note there are LOTS of small parts to go missing which might end up inside some child. As someone else mentioned, there are also some pretty sharp edges. Unless this is for some child labour chop-shop somewhere, (even then) I would suggest this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest voltage you are likely to see on the motherboard of a desktop PC is 12V.  Even if the capacitors aren't discharged, that's not going to kill anybody.  On a laptop, it could be up to 19V, which is still pretty harmless.

The PSU of a computer may have a few hundred volts when in use, but that should dissipate fairly quickly.  Leave the computers off for a few days, and it will be gone.

Beware of letting smaller children near all the bits left over after disassembling a computer.  The little backup batteries on the motherboard can be pretty nasty if swallowed, and the other components can contain all sorts of toxic chemicals.

Beware of shorting out laptop batteries, as lithium cells are notorious for catching fire

Answer (score 1):

The voltage on motherboard is very low and will not present danger. 
*UNLESS* it has build in PSU on motherboard which is very rare these day, they used to do that on 1980s/1990s old computer but not anymore due to CE certification and safety reason.

If you so concern, you can short whole motherboard with antistatic mat or foam.